# Kendo MVC Grid localisation for neutral cultures

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, internationalization, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

We're using the Kendo UI ASP.NET MVC wrappers to render our grids. I've got localisation working as described in [this article](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/globalization#localization) but the problem I have is that if the browser culture gets resolved as language neutral (just language level, for example "fr" instead of "fr-FR") the localisation doesn't work and the grid is rendered as "en-US".

Is there a simple way of making the wrappers use the localisations in this scenario?

I guess I could force the culture somehow and in the worst case compile the Kendo dll with additional resources but thought I would ask first.

Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've got a solution for now - I've made a culture switcher that I wrap in a using statement around the grid building code.

```
namespace Kendo.Mvc.UI
{
    public class KendoCultureSwitcher : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly CultureInfo _culture;
        private readonly List<string> _cultures = new List<string>()
        {
            "bg-BG",
            "cs-CZ",
            "da-DK",
            "de-DE",
            "es-ES",
            "fr-FR",
            "it-IT",
            "nl-NL",
            "pl-PL",
            "pt-PT", // Note before pt-BR
            "pt-BR",
            "ro-RO",
            "ru-RU",
            "sv-SE",
            "tr-TR",
            "uk-UA",
            "zh-CN"
        };

        public KendoCultureSwitcher()
        {
            _culture = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;

            var currentCultureName = _culture.ToString();
            if (!_cultures.Contains(currentCultureName, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                var switchCulture = _cultures.FirstOrDefault(c => c.StartsWith(currentCultureName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
                if (switchCulture != null)
                {
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(switchCulture);
                }
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture != _culture)
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = _culture;
            }
        }
    }
}
```